# Search regex pattern with PowerShell and output filename

Tags: regex, powershell, select-string

```
$input_path = "d:\txt\*.txt"
$output_file = 'd:\out.txt'
$regex = "\w* (\w\.? )?\w* (was )?[B|b]orn .{100}"
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

Powershell beginner here. I'd like it to loop through all files in a specific directory, search for a specific regex pattern and output the results to a file. So far I've managed to work out the above. How can I have it also output the filename for each match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
$input_path = "d:\txt\*.txt"
$output_file = 'd:\out.txt'
$regex = "\w* (\w\.? )?\w* (was )?[B|b]orn .{100}"
Select-String -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | Foreach-Object {
    $currentMatches = $_
    $_.Matches | Foreach-Object { $_.Value,$currentMatches.Filename -join ' | ' } |
        Add-Content $output_file
}
```

**Explanation:**

`Select-String` will return a collection of `MatchInfo` objects. Each of those objects has a `Filename` property that contains only the filename of the file containing the match(es). Since there could be multiple matches (due to `-AllMatches`) in a single file, it is necessary to iterate through each match within a `MatchInfo` object.

The `-join` operator joins all items in a collection with a defined string delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

So for your last line, use:

```
# put matches into var
$matches = Select-String -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches
# write out to file
foreach ($m in $matches) { $m.Filename | Out-File $output_file -Append -NoClobber }
```

Comment: Thank you RobotScience! I'll avoid aliases for now. Using your line I somehow still don't get the filename though. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Ah you wanted the filename, I updated my answer. Hopefully that works better for you.

Comment: Yes I was trying to get something like
`Stphn Lastname was born in 1995 xyz | 1.txt`
`Robot Science was born in 1996 xyz | 2.txt`